# Backbone.js calling function render from event handler

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I got my view like this :

```
render:function(){
    this.template = _.template(tpl.get('tplUsersManagement'));
    this.$el.html(this.template({models : this.model.models}));
    this.$el.i18n();
     $('#formAddUser')
     .on('invalid', function () {
            var invalid_fields = $(this).find('[data-invalid]');
        console.log(invalid_fields);
        })
     .on('valid', this.addUser);
        return this;
        },
addUser: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var newUser = new UserModel({
        . . .
    });
    var that=this;
    newUser.save({},{
            headers:{"X-Token":"theToken"},
            statusCode:{
                202: function(){
                    that.render();//here I want to call render function
                    }
                }});
            }

        }
```

So I want to call my render function from my addUser function. I try to do it with this=that and then that.render but I got an error and it says that :

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'render'

I think its because in the event handler this become my form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already aware of the context constraints and that's why you are using the `var that = this` trick, but there is another place you need to implement it:

```
var self = this; // I prefer "self" rather than "that" 
$('#formAddUser').on('invalid', function () {
  // handle invalid data
}).on('valid', function( ev ){
   ev.preventDefault();
   self.addUser();
   return this;
});
```

The `addUser` function is part of your view module, but within the `valid/invalid` event handlers, the context (the `this` variable) is changed. You'll need to keep a reference of the correct context (`var self = this;`) before entering the scope of the event handler so that it can be used to call your `addUser()` function.

Comment: Now I can call my render function , thanks , but my event.preventDefault() is not working anymore , any ideas ?

Comment: The actual event is happening in the function that calls `addUser`.  You'll want to move the `preventDefault` to just before you call `addUser`.

Comment: I already tried this ( sorry forgot I to say) , but it doesn't work , my form is still submit.

Answer (score 1):

There will be 2 options.

1.Use event delegation of backbone view. It will be let you use your view object in event handler.

2.Bind your addUser function to this.

```
addUser: function() {
...
//do something
...
}.bind(this)
```

Comment: Could you expand on your answer a little bit? Event delegation is part of backbone, but I'm not too sure where that bind function comes into play... Is that part of [backbone/underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)? Just plain [JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)?

Comment: Umm... If you use event delegation of backbone, backbone bind your event listener to view object. So this reference view object in event handler. In your case, it seems you are not using event delegation so this is not reference view object in event handler. 

If you bind your function to this explicitly, you can use view object as this in function without backbone's event delegation.

Comment: Just a note, I'm not the user asking the question :) I understand your first suggestion to use backbone methods, but I'm a little confused about your second suggestion. Could you insert some links to the relevant documentation please?

Comment: And bind is plain JS. underscore has it too.

Comment: Ah... I see. So you are talking about [this bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). You should try to add some more details to your answer. Not all users who browse the site have the same level of expertise.

Comment: Yep. btw... you are too fast response!

Comment: Hahaha... my fingers need to keep up with my brain :P